# How can I fix my re-replace-region function in which match data gets clobbered?

Tags: regular-expressions, replace, region

I have an ancient function I've been using for decades which performs a regexp replacement in a region:

```
(defun re-replace-region (begin end old new)
"Replace occurrences of REGEXP with TO-STRING in region."
  (interactive "*r\nsReplace string: \nswith: ")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region begin end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (re-search-forward old (point-max) t)
        (replace-match new (not case-replace) nil)))))
```

However, in recent emacs versions this function has started to fail with the message "Match data clobbered by buffer modification hooks".

I believe this can be fixed with judicious use of (save-match-data ...), but that doesn't seem to work for me.

How can this function be fixed?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: There have been upstream "Match data clobbered by buffer modification hooks" bugs in the past.  Your issue might have been an Emacs bug, and potentially now fixed.  Which version of Emacs was this?  Are you able to test with a newer one?

Comment: emacs version 27.1

Comment: Try to let-bin `before-change-functions` and `after-change-functions` to nil in your function. That way, the faulty hook isn't runed. (Of course, if could be a good idea to fid the culprit, which should be relative straight-forward once you found which hook variable it has attached itself to.)

Comment: Your code works as expected on Emacs 29.0.50, so perhaps this was a bug as @phils suggested, and has been fixed sometime since 27.1

Comment: It cannot be known whether this code works as expected in any particular Emacs version, because the bug most likely has to do with code registered to run from `before-change-hooks` and `after-change-hooks` hooks, which depends on the current mode, add on packages, etc.  See my answer for more: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74510/21036

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, and should work as written.

This is most likely a bug in some other Emacs Lisp code running from buffer "Change Hooks".  The problem may be in Emacs Lisp code that comes with Emacs, or it may be in an add on package you are using.

Here is what the [Change Hooks (GNU Emacs Lisp Manual)](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Change-Hooks.html) has to say about it:

> The functions you use in these hooks should save and restore the match
> data if they do anything that uses regular expressions; otherwise,
> they will interfere in bizarre ways with the editing operations that
> call them.

Theory: some other code in your Emacs is running from these change hooks and failing to save the match data, thus confusing your code.  That would be the bug.

To narrow this down you should look at the value of `before-change-hooks` and `after-change-hooks` when your `re-replace-region` function runs.  One of the functions in those hooks is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the built–in `replace-regexp` function? It operates on the region, if one is active.

Comment: Consider explaining or showing how it specifically answers the question, to make the answer more useful.

Comment: You mean mentioning that it’s completely bullet–proof? That it’s 550 lines long and calls `save-match-data` in two places and `set-match-data` in seven? Or that it would take a book to explain how it works so that he can update his own implementation?

Comment: replace-regexp seems to lose the region after the replace, making multiple replacements upon the one region quite difficult.

Comment: It deactivates the region, but it doesn’t “lose” it. The region is bounded on one end by the mark, and on the other by the point. You can use `exchange-point-and-mark` to reactivate the region (it is bound to `C-x C-x` by default). However, I suppose it is true that `replace-regexp` does not leave the point exactly where it was before you ran it; it places the point at the end of the last replacement. You may need to move the point back to the end of your region before using `C-x C-x`.

Comment: I have to say that the code shown in the question does *not* look remotely problematic to me.  Everything in that function is incredibly normal -- it's pretty much the canonical example of a search and replace in a region.  The standard command ought to work of course, but I don't think the custom one ought to be failing.

Comment: It is not clear that `replace-regexp` wouldn't suffer from the same problem.  See my other answer to this question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/74510/21036